# Network monitoring system with mobile app

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring, android

I'm looking for a monitoring system (that runs on linux) and can monitor the most used operational systems and has an application for android to show the status of the servers. Anyone knows a software that does that?

Comment: There are both apps, and a mobile interface for Nagios.

Comment: Cacti has an android app, not sure if its an official app but it works well; https://market.android.com/details?id=de.fabworxs.cactiviewer&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImRlLmZhYndvcnhzLmNhY3Rpdmlld2VyIl0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a more userfriendly configuration frontend, take a look at
https://www.nconf.org.
I messed around with it a lot and we are now using it in our produtive environment. In the newest version 1.3.0 they added many nice features, and updated authorization possibility (HTTP Basic Auth, Mysql, LDAP, Active Directory)

Another monitoring system that's working quite nice is Zabbix. There are apps for iOS, Android and maybe other platforms. Personally, I only have experiences with http://www.mozaby.com/.
Mobbix for Android sounds quite promising, I'm not sure whether it's already out of beta.
Zabbix itself includes a graphical interface for managing your configurations.
The notification system can be tuned quite extensivly and for now, I'm using it in a different environment, it's working like a charm for me.

Both can work with and without agents. You should dig deeper into the feature list to decide according to your special needs.

That being said, we are actually not using Nagios, but Icinga, which is a fork of Nagios. I don't know about the current state of Nagios, but for Icinga there is a fully redesigned, separate installable web gui called Icinga Web and they offer (Attention! Alpha!) Icinga Mobile, a mobile web frontend. Which is, of course, not dependent on your smartphone OS.

[Edit:] The notification system of Zabbix can use email, Jabber, SMS and you are able to define new media types which are actually server based scripts that do the magic you want.

Comment: thanks, I will look into all this softwares, specially nconf. I've used Zabbix before, but haven't used the mobile interfaces yet.

Answer (score 1):

[nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) Is widely used for monitoring.  [nagdroid](https://github.com/dantheta/nagdroid) Is an open source monitoring app for android which will poll your nagios server for status.  Its available in the android market as well.

Comment: might i add aNag from market.android.com is an excellent android client to nagios !

Answer (score 0):

As stew said, Nagios is one of the most mature monitoring systems and it have lots of Android apps that you can use to have the status screen.

For really big environments it's not a good idea to manage all the alerts through the graphical interface and to avoid problems you can configure a notification to be sent directly to any xmpp account (like google talk, icq...) that can also be accessed through a mobile phone.

You have an example in this post: http://www.techadre.com/content/tweak-nagios-jabber-xmpp-notifications